# Xcode 6.4 or Mapbox sdk bug causes warning in RMShape.h

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mapbox

Since I've updated my Xcode to 6.4 I'm getting warnings like this in my project:

> ..../AppName/Mapbox/Headers/RMShape.h:81:38: 'atomic' attribute on
>   property 'shadowOffset' does not match the property inherited from
>   'CALayer'

It's interesting because I didn't edited anything in the Mapbox SDK and the pre-defined property is nonatomic in the `RMShape.h` file `@property (nonatomic, assign) CGSize shadowOffset;` so I don't know what's going on. Does anybody experienced the same? Is it an Xcode 6.4 related issue or a bug in the Mapbox sdk?